# Packer fails my docker build with error "sudo: not found" despite sudo being present

Tags: docker, packer

I'm trying to build a packer image with docker on it and I want docker to create a docker image with a custom script. The relevant portion of my code is (note that the top builder double-checks that sudo is installed):

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "inline": [
    "apt-get install sudo"
  ]
},
{
  "type": "docker",
  "image": "python:3",
  "commit": true,
  "changes": [
    "RUN pip install Flask",
    "CMD [\"python\", \"echo.py\"]"
  ]
}
```

The relevant portion of my screen output is:

```
==> docker: provisioning with shell script: /var/folders/s8/g1_gobbldygook/T/packer-shell23453453245
    docker: /temp/script_1234.sh: 3: /tmp/script_1234.sh: sudo: not found
==> docker: killing the contaner: 34234hashvomit234234
Build 'docker' errored: Scipt exited with non-zero exit status: 127
```

The script in question is not one of mine. It's some randomly generated script that has a different series of four numbers every time I build. I'm new to both packer and docker, so maybe it's obvious what the problem is, but it's not to me.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few problems with your packer input.  Since you haven't included the complete input file it's hard to tell, but notice a couple of things:

1. You probably need to run `apt-get update` before calling `apt-get install sudo`.  Without that, even if the image has cached package metadata it is probably stale.  If I try to build an image using your input it fails with:

   ```
   E: Unable to locate package sudo
   ```
2. While not a problem in this context, it's good to explicitly include `-y` on the `apt-get` command line when you're running it non-interactively:

   apt-get -y install sudo

   In situations where `apt-get` is attached to a terminal, this will prevent it from prompting for confirmation. This is not a *necessary* change to your input, but I figure it's good to be explicit.
3. Based on [the docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html) and on my testing, you can't include a `RUN` statement in the `changes` block of a docker builder.  That fails with:

   ```
   Stderr: Error response from daemon: run is not a valid change command
   ```

   Fortunately, we can move that `pip install` command into a `shell` provisioner.

With those changes, the following input successfully builds an image:

```
{
    "builders": [{
        "type": "docker",
        "image": "python:3",
        "commit": true
    }],

    "provisioners": [{
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": [
          "apt-get update",
          "apt-get -y install sudo",
          "pip install Flask"
        ]
    }],

    "post-processors": [[ {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "packer-test",
        "tag": "latest"
    } ]]
}
```

(**NB**: Tested using Packer v1.3.5)